# Cannot assign permission set to Guest User

Tags: permission-sets, guest-user

I need to assign a permission set ("B2B Commerce Guest Access") to a guest user ("Site Guest User"). When I click save I get this error message

> Can't complete this operation because you reached the limit of 0 of
> standard apps for Site Guest User for the Guest User License user
> license.

[image]

This article didn't help https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387961&type=1 since there are no apps assigned in profile and permission set.

Comment: Worth reading [Guest User Security Policies and Timelines](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_guest_policies_timelines.htm&type=5). There might be an answer on your question.